# Web scraping from chronotrack running results with python

Tags: python, web, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape results from a platform the running events results chronotrack.
As an example, you can see the results for Santiago de Chile marathon 2022 on this link: https://results.chronotrack.com/event/results/event/event-74000

Based on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678046/python-web-scrape-selenium-requests), I managed to get a url that provides a json with the results for a specific event. I can modify the number of results displayed, so they are all shown in one page, and I don't need to iterate over several pages

Here's an example of setting up a url, and read the json data:

```
# create url
displaylength = 20000
event = 74000 # santiago 2023
# event = 49653 # santiago 2019

link = (
    'https://results.chronotrack.com/embed/results/results-grid?callback=results_grid17740402&sEcho=7' + 
    f'&iColumns=11&sColumns=&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength={displaylength}' +
    f'&mDataProp_0=0&mDataProp_1=1&mDataProp_2=2&mDataProp_3=3&mDataProp_4=4&mDataProp_5=5&mDataProp_6=6&mDataProp_7=7&mDataProp_8=8&mDataProp_9=9&mDataProp_10=10' +
    f'&raceID=60107&bracketID=638654&intervalID=121077&entryID=&eventID={event}&eventTag=event-{event}' +
    '&oemID=www.chronotrack.com&genID=17740402&x=1507682443198&_=1507682443198'
)


# read data
with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as url:
    data = url.read().decode('utf-8')

intro = 'results_grid17740402('
dic = json.loads(data[len(intro):-2])
```

However, I can't find a way to choose the right race (10K, 21K, 42K) or category of runners (Overall men, Women over 40, etc.). I tried twiking the numbers after "raceID", "bracketID", and "intervalID" on the url, but it seems they don't really make a difference on the data shown.

Any hint how could I select the right race and category while creating the link?

However, I can't find a way to choose the right race (10K, 21K, 42K) or category of runners (Overall men, Women over 40, etc.). I tried twiking the numbers after "raceID", "bracketID", and "intervalID" on the url, but it seems they don't really make a difference on the data shown.

Any hint how could I select the right race and category while creating the link?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to change `raceID`/`bracketID`/`intervalID` to get correct results:

```py
import json

import requests

api_url = "https://results.chronotrack.com/embed/results/results-grid"

# for 10K
raceID = 192767
bracketID = 2143412
intervalID = 479537

# for 42K
# raceID = 192769
# bracketID = 2143466
# intervalID = 479543

params = {
    "callback": "results_grid99708633",
    "sEcho": "7",
    "iColumns": "11",
    "sColumns": "",
    "iDisplayStart": "0",
    "iDisplayLength": "9999",
    "mDataProp_0": "0",
    "mDataProp_1": "1",
    "mDataProp_2": "2",
    "mDataProp_3": "3",
    "mDataProp_4": "4",
    "mDataProp_5": "5",
    "mDataProp_6": "6",
    "mDataProp_7": "7",
    "mDataProp_8": "8",
    "mDataProp_9": "9",
    "mDataProp_10": "10",
    "raceID": raceID,
    "bracketID": bracketID,
    "intervalID": intervalID,
    "entryID": "",
    "eventID": "74000",
    "eventTag": "event-74000",
    "oemID": "www.chronotrack.com",
    "genID": "99708633",
    "x": "1701210896091",
    "_": "1701210896092",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).text

data = json.loads(data[data.index("{") : -2])

for d in data["aaData"]:
    print(d[2])
```

Prints:

```
Diego Ignacio Uribe Troncoso
Matias Andres Silva Lastra
Raúl Moya Vásquez
Ignacio Alexander Carrizo Godoy
Luis Gustavo Huaman Matamoros
Rodrigo Machado Hamilton
Luis Valle Barrientos
Luis Miguel Bustos Hormazabal

...
```

Comment: Thanks, this is great. I have no idea how you got those numbers. 
Just to complement, these are the values for the 21K:

raceID = {'10K': 192767, '21K': 192768, '42K': 192769}
bracketID = {'10K': 2143412, '21K': 2143439, '42K': 2143466}
intervalID = {'10K': 479537, '21K': 479540, '42K': 479543}